# creating sql table with foreign key error no:150

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I've tried to create a table,with 2 foreign key but when I tried to write it into mysql, get an error says "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table  (errno: 150)" Is there anyone to help me ? Here is my tables:

```
  create table store (
  StoreName varchar(255),
  Category varchar(20),
  primary key(StoreName,Category));




 create table shopps (
 StoreName varchar(255),
 Category varchar(20),
 primary key(StoreName,Category),
 foreign key(StoreName) References store);
 foreign key(Category) References store);
```

Comment: In the unedited version of your question was table with another name (shopping). Are you sure the error occurs because of store or shopps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `store` table has a composite primary key, the foreign key referencing it in the `shopps` table must be composite as well:

```
create table shopps (
    StoreName varchar(255),
    Category varchar(20),
    primary key(StoreName,Category),
    foreign key(StoreName,Category) References store (StoreName,Category)
)
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/457b49)